# Binding the Source Property in the WPF WebBrowser Won't Accept Fragment

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control

I have a WPF WebBrowser with the Source Property bound to another object's string property.  When I change the other object's string, the browser updates properly to the new address, so I know the binding is working properly.  I'm using local (file:///) urls.

The issue I'm having is when the url has a fragment, e.g. `file:///path/page.html#anchor1`.  In that case, the Source property is set with the Uri, but it doesn't take -- when I look at the Source property after the set, the value is unchanged.

```
public static void BindableSourcePropertyChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    WebBrowser browser = o as WebBrowser;
    if (browser != null)
    {
        Uri uri = e.NewValue as Uri;

        if (uri != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(uri.OriginalString))
        {
            browser.Source = uri;
        }
    }
}
```

I've single-stepped through to make sure that the uri is correct and the `browser.Source = uri;` statement executes.  No exception is thrown.  It just doesn't set the Source value when the Uri has a fragment.

I wrote a small example where I set a WebBrowser's Source property directly with a Uri containing a fragment, and it worked fine.

This one has me scratching my head . . .

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? Have a similar issue...

Answer (score 1):

I ended up just calling the Navigate() method instead.

```
public static void BindableSourcePropertyChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebBrowser browser = o as WebBrowser;
        if (browser != null)
        {
            string uri = e.NewValue as string;                
            browser.Navigate(uri);
        }
    }
```